# How can I apply the concordance method (from nlkt) to each line on my Data Frame to find all the contexts which appear a set of words that I defined?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I want to apply the concordance method to each line of messages in my column of messages to figure out the contexts in which these words (study, studies etc.) appear.

```
df['Message_tokenized'] = df['Message_tokenized'].apply(Text) 
df['Concordance_Results'] = df['Message_tokenized'].apply(lambda text: text.concordance(r'\b(?:study|studies|studying|studied|learn|learning|learned|homework|research|researching|papers?|presentation|thesis|tests?|finals|grades?)\b'))
```

When I run this code the output gets "no matches" tho. How can i do it?

Comment: What makes you think `.concordance` accepts a regex? It accepts a simple literal string or string list.

Comment: it is also not working in simple strings

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example.